# The second while loop is running endlessly can someone please explain why?

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner

I am trying to get a hang of multiple inputs but I have run into a problem that I cant seem to understand.

I have tried debugging and I have understood where the logical error is occurring but I cant seem to understand why.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int i=0;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int T=sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        while(T!=0)
        {
            System.out.println("First Loop");
           while(sc.hasNext()) {
               System.out.println("Second loop");
               int j=sc.nextInt();
               i=i+j;
           }
           sc.nextLine();
           T=T-1;
        }
        System.out.println("end");
    }
}


2<br>
First Loop<br>
1 2 3 4 5<br>
Second loop<br>
Second loop<br>
Second loop<br>
Second loop<br>
Second loop<br>
1 2 3 4 5<br>
Second loop<br>
Second loop<br>
Second loop<br>
Second loop<br>
Second loop<br>
1 2 3 4 5<br>
Second loop<br>
Second loop<br>
Second loop<br>
Second loop<br>
Second loop<br>
```

This is whats happening and on and on it goes. Its an endless loop.

The first line is the number of test cases so the second loop should run twice in this given case however its running endlessly

Comment: Why do you need another `while` loop? `sc.hasNext()` will always return `true` since you keep giving the input. Maybe change it to `sc.hasNextInt()` so that you can quit the loop by inputting a non integer input

Comment: I guess you want to have the inner loop run exactly once per line. However, `sc.hasNext()` ignores line endings, so this loop will not terminate at the end of a line. Are the lines of your input format really that dynamic or do you know how many values you expect per line?

Comment: The second loop should test the same thing it is using, i.e. either `hasNext()` and `next()`, or `hasNextInt()` amd `nextInt()`. Not a mixture.

Comment: what is your requirement? This problem is not clear. How do you want to run the code? What is your expectation?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand what you're trying to do here with 2 while loops, but you can fix the infinite loop problem by simply doing

```
while(sc.hasNextInt()) { //change here
    System.out.println("Second loop");
    int j=sc.nextInt();
    i=i+j;
}
```

Basically, `hasNext()` will always return `true` However, `hasNextInt()` returns true only if you give it an integer. So you can exit the loop by entering non integer input.

When reading files, `hasNext()` will ultimately return `false` when the end of file is reached. However, when you read keyboard input, it will obviously never return `false`.